# How to add a Adobe Analytics Variable to multiple Link Track rule in Dynamic Tag Manager

Tags: adobe-analytics

I have more than 100 DTM rules which has been set up to capture Analytics link track. Now, I have new requirement to add one global variable (let's say eVarX) to all of the link tracking. Could someone please help me how it can be done without adding it manually to each link track rule.

Answer (score 1):

DTM does not currently have a way to globally add variables to all Adobe Analytics (AA) hits. The closest thing you can do is make use of AA's `doPlugins` callback function, which you can define in the custom code box of the AA tool config page.

If you do not already have `doPlugins` (commonly namespaced `s_doPlugins`) function defined there, then in the custom code box of the Adobe Analytics tool, add the following:

```
s.usePlugins=true;
s.doPlugins=function(s) {

  // add variable here
  // make sure to also "register" it in `linkTrackVars` 
  // for s.tl calls

}
```

**Note:** This is *global*, as in, it will trigger for *all* `s.t` and `s.tl` calls, not just those specific 100 DTM rules. There's no good way to effectively say "only do it for [some list of rules]" except to just individually add it to your rules.